# cookies and verification problem in scraping

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, data-science, screen-scraping, data-mining

After running this code as part of a project, in order to enter login screen :

```
import pandas as pd


import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
import os



output = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\97254\\Downloads\\output.xlsx")

url = "https://www.tandfonline.com/loi/nvpp20"


from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get(url)


driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"sign-in-link").click()
time.sleep(5)
```

This screen  [human verification] appeared. moreover, when the website was loaded, there was a screen asking to accept cookies [enter image description here]. Is there a selenium method dealing with these problem?
Thanks

Comment: Any feedback on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76632449/7429447) to your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76632422/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

To click on the ***cookie*** element <kbd>Accept</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.tandfonline.com/loi/nvpp20")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#cookie-accept"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.tandfonline.com/loi/nvpp20")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='cookie-accept']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: It worked. However, the website referred me to human verification screen - so I can't move forward to login... can I combine selenium with undetected_chromedriver library to avoid the cookie problem and being recognized as a robot ?